# How remove fabric.js object and events

Tags: javascript, iframe, fabricjs

I use fabric.js with vue and additional lib iframe to allow user draw. In the beginning, I have my div for rendering (for fabric.js) in main window. When I enable drawing mode, I create new fabric, and then, move div.canvas-container into my iframe.

When user ends drawing, I moved canvas-container to my main window back, and then call:

```
this.fabric.dispose()
$(this.fabric.wrapperEl).remove()
```

But it doesn't remove canvas-container, I also have a lot of errors in console because of onmove events - I set them on drawing and use off to disable, also dispose should remove them, but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle of it?

Comment: Unfortunately, not, it's too complicated.